# Populating angular event from hild to parent

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to fire an event from parent and subscribe it from parent component.

```
import { Component, Output, Input, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p>Hello</p>
    <parent [name]="settings.parentSettings.name" (subCreated)="onSubCreated()">
      <sub [name]="settings.subSettings.name"></sub>
    </parent>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  settings:any ={
    parentSettings: {
      name: "P"
    },
    subSettings:{
      name: "S"
    }
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `<ng-container></ng-container>`
})
export class ParentComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  onSubCreated(){
    console.log("on sub created.");
  }
}



@Component({
  selector: 'sub',
  template: `<ng-container></ng-container>`
})
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Output() subCreated: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subCreated.emit();
  }
}
```

So, is there any way to fire onSubCreated() in ParentComponent? I do not want to move `<sub [name]="settings.subSettings.name"></sub>` in ParentComponent template.

[Stackblitz working applcation is here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ach9uh)

Comment: child to parent -- @Output

Comment: I want to fire an event **from parent and subscribe it from parent component.** I don't get it.    **onSubCreated() in MainComponent?** where is MainComponent?

Comment: please be explicit about parents as there is multi-level hierarchy, so its hard to understand your problem

Comment: @phat.huynh, sorry I updated name. Not MainComponent it is ParentComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
 <parent [name]="settings.parentSettings.name" #parent>
      <sub [name]="settings.subSettings.name" (subCreated)="parent.onSubCreated()">
    </parent>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: your solution is worked. Thanks. Why use #parent, what does it mean?

Comment: It's called ViewRef or something, I don't remember but just know how to use :-) Like your mark it a name then you can use it on view or on component by @ViewChild('parent') (hahaha, I'm stupid)